# how to move file to different destination PHP

Tags: php, file, move

I want to move example.txt file on my server (`/var/www/tmp`) to different destination (`/var/www/tmp/dir`). I want to have this file only in one destination in which is file moved, so only one file on server. I have tried  many commands but I wasn't sucessful. Can you help me with this issue? Thanks.

Source code:

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php

   // variables from the form
   $blogentry = $_POST['blogentry'];

    // creating or opening the file in append mode
    $dataFile = "example.txt"; 
    $fh = fopen($dataFile, 'a');

    // writing to the file
    fwrite($fh,"". " " . $blogentry . " " . "\n\n");    
    fclose($fh);
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't you have any error message?

Answer (score 2):

You would use PHP's [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function to move files (the name of the function can be a little confusing).

```
rename("/var/www/tmp/file.txt", "/var/www/tmp/dir/file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just use the `rename()` function. From http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php:

```
rename("var/www/tmp/example.txt", "/var/www/tmp/dir/example.txt");
```

Comment: When I use command: rename("example.txt", "example2.txt"); it works. It makes file with name  example2.txt. But when I use command: rename("var/www/tmp/example.txt", "/var/www/tmp/dir/example2.txt"); it only create file example.txt and doesn't create example2.txt.

Comment: My answer is identical to the one above which was upvoted.  They should both work.

Comment: I have tried it once again but it doesn't work. It doesn't make file in different folder, it only create file in the current folder. :(